# Animating the Opacity doesn't work properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the `Opacity` of an element when I scroll down. and change the opacity back to its normal state when I scroll back to the top. But I'm having problems doing this.

```
#menu
{
    opacity:0.6
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $( "#menu" ).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    } else {
        $( "#menu" ).fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
    }
});
```

The above code doesn't work or in some cases it works after a bit and stops again! I'm really confused cause I tried the code below to simply fade it and it works without a hitch.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $( "#menu" ).fadeOut();
    } else {
        $( "#menu" ).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding animations is not that easy, because they introduce asynchronous behavior. Here, you're restarting the animations on every `scroll` event, even if the previously triggered animations are still active. Depending on your requirements, you could stop the current animation, or prevent animated elements from fading again, or use CSS3 transitions as IanS does in their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function ()
    {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 100) 
        {
            $('#menu').addClass('no-opacity');
        } 
        else
        {
            $('#menu').removeClass('no-opacity');
        }
    });
```

in css:

```
.no-opacity { opacity:0; }
```

in css again: make the change happen gradually:

```
#menu { transition: all 0.5s linear 0s; }
```

Comment: Thanks IanS, actually your answer suits my case better, since I want to change some other properties as well. I can do that using this method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend to use `.stop()` before `fadeTo` method, as you are executing it on every `scroll` event!

After that, your two code blocks are not the same, in the first one, you are showing element (opacity 1) if scroll is greater than 100, the second code is vice versa, try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $( "#menu" ).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
    } else {
        $( "#menu" ).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qcnL59n2/).

Comment: Thank you so much ROX, I guessed that some loop thing is happening there. So the secret was to use `.Stop()` before `.fadeTo()`

Answer (score 1):

To make it short, you could do it like this:

#### js

```
var _st;
$(window).scroll(function ()
{
    _st = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#menu').css({opacity:(_st > 100) ? 0 : 1 });
})
```

#### css

```
#menu { transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s; }
```

Comment: Note that using 'opacity' instead of 'all' in your css transition is better and faster.